# What is the benefit of `await_ready` in C++ coroutine awaiters

Tags: c++, async-await, coroutine, c++-coroutine

In C++ coroutines, awaiters-types (i. e. argument-types of `co_await` and return types of `initial_suspend`/`final_suspend`) require the three methods `await_ready()`, `await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<...>)` and `await_resume()`. I am aware of the order of invocation<sup>1</sup> in case of suspension/resumption of a coroutine.

But it is unclear to me what is the rationale of demanding the distinct `await_ready`-method. When returning `true` invocation of `await_suspend` is prevented (and with it suspension altogether). However, the same effect is achievable by simply returning `true` from `await_suspend`.

In [this](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/c++-coroutines.html) blog article the author David Mazières says

> `await_ready` is an optimization. If it returns `true`, then `co_await` does not suspend the function. Of course, you could achieve the same effect in `await_suspend`, by resuming (or not suspending) the current coroutine, but before calling `await_suspend`, the compiler must bundle all state into the heap object referenced by the coroutine handle, which is potentially expensive.

However, to me this does not seem to be a valid argument: The (possibly heap-)allocated coroutine state needs to be created before `promise_type::get_return_object()` is invoked which is *always* invoked, since the `promies_type`-instance is *part of* the coroutine state. Therefore the coroutine state referenced by the handle is created *anyway*, regardless of whether we will invoke `await_suspend` or not.

Back to the question putting my thougths into code: I do not see in which case the rewriting of

```
struct awaiter
{
  bool await_ready() { /* <arbitrary-await-ready-body> */ }
  void /*| bool*/ await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<...>) { /* <arbitrary-await-suspend-body> */ }

  <any> await_resume() { ... }
};
```

to

```
struct awaiter
{
  bool await_ready() { return false; } // always false
  bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<...>)
  {
    if (await_ready_result()) // effectively moved await_ready into await_suspend
      return false;
    /* <arbitrary-await-suspend-body> */
    return true;
  }

  <any> await_resume() { ... }
private:
  bool await_ready_result() { /* <arbitrary-await-ready-body> */ }; // could just be "in-lined" into await_suspend
};
```

would **not** be applicable. In the latter case `awaiter_ready` is obsolete without giving away any flexibility<sup>2</sup>. **So what is the use of distinct `awaiter_ready` at all?**

<sub>One thing that came to my mind was that `await_ready` could be kept `noexcept` when `await_suspend`'s implementation is arbitrarily complex, which might allow for some optimization but that seems overly specific to be the actual rationale.</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup>: See for example the pseudo code block in section *The Awaiter Workflow* of article https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/a-generic-data-stream-with-coroutines-in-c-20

<sup>2</sup>: I neglect the case of `await_suspend` returning some `std::coroutine_handle`, mainly because I don't see the particular use of that either. After all you could simply just call `some_handle.resume()` as last statement instead of returning it and instead return `void`/`true`. Feel free to enlighten me about that one as well.

Comment: To answer your second footnote, please see https://lewissbaker.github.io/2020/05/11/understanding_symmetric_transfer. Long story short, there are certain scenarios where you would overflow your stack because, by resuming the coroutine from your awaiter, your current coroutine frame would still be active. If you return the coroutine to be resumed, you would be "symmetrically transfering" to that one (that is to say, you would be on the same depth).

Comment: Secondly, although the coroutine frame is always created (if not optimized out), I don't think that should be construed with saving coroutine state. That is to say, if `await_ready()` returns `true`, then state needn't be saved. As a disclaimer, I'm actually not entirely sure about what the required behaviour is (as in I could be totally wrong), so this is just a comment for now.

Comment: @MonatheMonad You're right. The `await_ready() = true` avoids "suspending" the coroutine, only for `await_suspend` to say "nevermind" (return `false`) and force it to "resume" immediately. "Suspending" a coroutine means spilling all registers to memory, and "resuming" means reloading state from memory. In "The Awaiter Workflow", there is a step called "suspend coroutine" which is the "spill everything" step. It omits the "resume coroutine" which happens immediately after "resumptionPoint" (and which `await_ready=true` bypasses).

Comment: The state referred to by "the compiler must bundle all state into the heap object referenced by the coroutine handle" is not just the `promise_type`. It's also all of the coroutine local variables that are being held in registers.